# Multiple column values in where clause

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to display the Single user schedule for every week like Timetable ,

Scenario : A faculty is assigned to Multiple batches in a single week (E.g : BBA,Maths and Forenoon for Hour 1 and 2) & (MBA, Maths, Forenoon for Hour 3&4) in a same date say (30-06-2015).I row of gridview will store as 1 and 2 row as stores as 2 and so on.........

My Table Definition :

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[test] (
    [datedif]     NVARCHAR (50)  NOT NULL,
    [hour]         INT              NULL,
    [subject]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [faculty]    NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [attendence] BIT            NULL,
    [dayweek]     NVARCHAR (50)  NULL,
    [weekmonth]   NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [batch]       NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [section]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL,
    [session]     NVARCHAR (MAX) NULL
);
```

Table Looks Like :

```
Datefdiff | hour | subject | faulty| batch
----------+-------+----------+---------+-------+----------+--------+-------+----------+---------+-------
30-06-2015| 1| Maths    | Kevin   | BBA
30-06-2015| 2| Science  | Amal    | MBA
30-06-2015|3 | chemistry|Jaya     |BBA
30-06-2015|4 | chemistry|Jaya     |BBA 
30-06-2015|5 | chemistry|Jaya     |BBA
31-06-2015 |1| science  | Amal    |BBA
31-06-2015 |2| Maths    | kevin   |BBA 
31-06-2015 |3| Science  | Amal    |BBA 
31-06-2015 |4 | chemistry|Jaya     |BBA
31-06-2015 |5| science  | Amal    |BBA
```

Expected Output to be given for only the Faculty: Amal

```
Datefdiff |hour|subject| batch |hour|subject | batch |faculty|hour | subject | batch | hour | subject | batch| hour | subject | batch | 
----------+-------+----------+-------+-------+----------+-------+-------+----------+
30-06-2015| 1    | Maths| BBA| 2| Science  | MBA   | 3| Science  |   BBA| 4| chemistry| BBA | 5 |Physics |MBA
31-06-2015| 1    | Maths| BBA| 2| Science  | MBA   | 3| Science  |   BBA| 4| chemistry| BBA | 5 |Physics |MBA
```

[image]

Comment: That's a bad table design. You shouldn't be storing data to mimic some display/form. The data should be unpivotted so that all e.g. `subject` data ends up in the *same* column. And then add an extra column that can store numbers 1-5 and give that column a *name* that explains what that data represents (the data that you've currently embedded into the table *metadata* by mistake)

Comment: Thanks you for a suggestion, Still if i can get the to show the details of the faculty schedule by using it in a where clause it would be helpful, meanwhile i will try to change the Table definition as you suggested.

Comment: While you are changing the table definition, keep in mind that date values should be stored in date data types, and nvarchar(max) is for extreamly long unicode strings. since your strings seems to be both short and plain english, you can use varchar(50) or any other length that suits your needs. Also, I would recommend to normalize your data - have a table for subjects, a table for batch, a table for faulty and so on.

Comment: Nvarchar(max) - BAD IDEA !!!

Comment: Your table is not normalized. Fix your database design.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be a starting point for your table design:

```
declare @tbFaculty table (
      FacultyID int --identity(1,1) primary key
    , Name varchar(50)
)

insert into @tbFaculty ( FacultyID, Name )
values    ( 1, 'Kevin' )
        , ( 2, 'Amal' )

declare @tbBatch table(
      BatchID int --identity(1,1) primary key
    , Name char(3)
)

insert into @tbBatch ( BatchID, Name )
values    ( 1, 'BBA' )
        , ( 2, 'MBA' )

declare @tbClass table (
      [Hour] tinyint
    , [Subject] nvarchar (128)
    , [FacultyID] int
    , [Attendence] bit
    , [BatchID] char(3)
    , [ClassDate] date
)

insert into @tbClass ( [Hour], [Subject], FacultyID, Attendence, BatchID, ClassDate )
values    ( 1, 'Maths', 1, 1, 1, '2015-06-30' )
        , ( 2, 'Maths', 1, 1, 1, '2015-06-30' )
        , ( 3, 'Science', 2, 1, 1, '2015-06-30' )
        , ( 1, 'Science', 2, 1, 2, '2015-06-30' )
        , ( 2, 'Science', 2, 1, 2, '2015-06-30' )
        , ( 3, 'Maths', 1, 1, 2, '2015-06-30' )

select
    cl.ClassDate
    , cl.[Hour]
    , cl.[Subject]
    , ba.Name as BatchName
    , fa.Name as FacultyName
from
    @tbClass cl
    inner join @tbBatch ba on ba.BatchID = cl.BatchID
    inner join @tbFaculty fa on fa.FacultyID = cl.FacultyID
where
    fa.Name = 'Amal'
```

You could normalize the Subject as well.

Answer (score 1):

I'm just going to add this a s a separate answer. Try this out:

```
--INSERT INTO dbo.test(datedif,[hour],[subject],faculty,batch)
--VALUES
--('30-06-2015',1,'Maths','Kevin','BBA'),
--('30-06-2015',2,'Science','Amal','MBA'),
--('30-06-2015',3,'chemistry','Jaya','BBA'),
--('30-06-2015',4,'chemistry','Jaya','BBA'),
--('30-06-2015',5,'chemistry','Jaya','BBA'),
--('31-06-2015',1,'science','Amal','BBA'),
--('31-06-2015',2,'Maths','kevin','BBA'),
--('31-06-2015',3,'Science','Amal','BBA'),
--('31-06-2015',4,'chemistry','Jaya','BBA'),
--('31-06-2015',5,'science','Amal','BBA');

WITH CTE_Hours
AS
(
    SELECT
            1 AS hour1,
            MAX(CASE WHEN [Hour] = 1 THEN [subject] END)    AS subject1,
            MAX(CASE WHEN [Hour] = 1 THEN [batch] END)      AS batch1 ,

            2 AS hour2,
            MAX(CASE WHEN [Hour] = 2 THEN [subject] END)    AS subject2,
            MAX(CASE WHEN [Hour] = 2 THEN [batch] END)      AS batch2

            --etc...
    FROM dbo.test
    WHERE faculty = 'Amal'
)

SELECT *
FROM    (
            SELECT DISTINCT datedif
            FROM dbo.test
        ) A
CROSS JOIN CTE_Hours
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to normalize your data which will make querying it MUCH simpler.

Using your table definition, I inserted your data

```
INSERT INTO test(Datedif,hour1,subject1,faculty1,hour2,subject2,faculty2,hour3,subject3,faculty3,batch)
VALUES  ('30-06-2015',1,'Maths','Kevin',1,'Maths','Kevin',1,'Science','Amal','BBA'),
        ('30-06-2015',1,'Science','Amal',1,'Science','Amal',1,'Maths','Kevin','MBA');
```

Then I created a new normalized structure for your data with narrower datatypes. It helps keep your data clean as well as not wasting storage space meaning queries will be faster as they don't have to process so much data.

```
CREATE TABLE new_test
(
    dt          DATE            NULL,
    hr          TINYINT         NULL, --holds values between 0 to 255
    subj        VARCHAR(100)    NULL, --plenty big enough. No need for NVARCHAR unless you are using Unicode characters
    faculty     VARCHAR(100)    NULL,
    attendance  BIT             NULL,
    dayweek     TINYINT         NULL,
    weekmonth   TINYINT         NULL,
    section     VARCHAR(100)    NULL, --not sure what this is
    sess        VARCHAR(100)    NULL, --not sure what this is
    batch       CHAR(3)         NULL  --looks like there are three character codes
);
```

This is where I normalize your data. I'm not sure if you have attendance2,3,4 etc... If you do in your actual table, then you should fix my code.

**Note:** I calculated dayweek and weekmonth from date. I did my best guess, if they are incorrect, then feel free to adjust them!

```
WITH norm_data
AS
(
SELECT datedif,hour1,subject1,faculty1,attendence1,dayweek,weekmonth,section,[session],batch FROM test
UNION ALL
SELECT datedif,hour2,subject2,faculty2,attendence1,dayweek,weekmonth,section,[session],batch FROM test
UNION ALL
SELECT datedif,hour3,subject3,faculty3,attendence1,dayweek,weekmonth,section,[session],batch FROM test
UNION ALL
SELECT datedif,hour4,subject4,faculty4,attendence1,dayweek,weekmonth,section,[session],batch FROM test
UNION ALL
SELECT datedif,hour5,subject5,faculty5,attendence1,dayweek,weekmonth,section,[session],batch FROM test
)

INSERT INTO new_test
SELECT  PARSE(datedif AS DATE USING 'de-DE') AS [datedif],
        hour1,
        subject1,
        faculty1,
        attendence1,
        DATEPART(WEEKDAY,PARSE(datedif AS DATE USING 'de-DE')) AS dayweek,
        datepart(day, datediff(day, 0, PARSE(datedif AS DATE USING 'de-DE'))/7 * 7)/7 + 1 AS weekmonth,
        section,
        [session],
        batch
FROM norm_data
```

Now let's look at your new table

```
SELECT *
FROM new_test
```

If it's correct, then here's how to rename the tables

```
EXEC SP_rename  @objname = 'test', --if you don't want to drop the old table
                @newname = 'test_old'

EXEC SP_rename  @objname = 'new_test', --now give the new table the actual name
                @newname = 'test'


SELECT *
FROM test
```

Comment: I have changed my table according to your suggestion.You can see my changed table above.How can I Join them and show in grid view.Please suggest me some idea.See the above grid view like wise I should get the output